# How to create custom chat icon using css only

Tags: html, css

I want to create chat icon using css only. Here's a sample of it:
[image]

I don't want to use bootstrap chat icons because it's hard to customize especially the numbers inside the icon grows.

Comment: My suggestion would be to write some css then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit like what you have in your request.

```css
.msg1,
.msg2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.msg1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #ff6781;
  color: white;
}

.msg2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #ff6781;
  color: #ff6781;
}

.msg1 p,
.msg2 p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.msg1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff6781;
  top: 89%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.msg1:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff6781;
  top: 89%;
  left: 48%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.msg2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff6781;
  top: 100%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 6px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.msg2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ff6781;
  top: 100%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 3px;
  height: 6px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="msg1"><p>4</p></div>
<div class="msg2"><p>11</p></div>
```

second solution:

```css
.msg1,
.msg2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.msg1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #ff6781;
  color: white;
}

.msg2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #ff6781;
  color: #ff6781;
}

.msg1 p,
.msg2 p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.msg1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 33%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ff6781;
}

.msg2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ff6781;
}
```

```html
<div class="msg1"><p>4</p></div>
<div class="msg2"><p>11</p></div>
```

Comment: I will make the second decision. In it, bottom terrugolics are made with one pseudo-class `after`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.chat-icon {
    color: #161616;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.balloon {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.stick {
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-icon">
    <div class="balloon">10</div>
    <div class="stick"></div>
</div>
```